# Show that any subset of a metric space is open

Tags: metric-spaces

Here's a problem:
[image]

I've done the first 2 parts but I have no idea of how to approach part iii, and I'm very confused for part iv because isn't a singleton set a closed subset?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It is not true that any subset of a metric space is open.  If you don't care enough to type up the question and show some effort, I don't care enough to click through.

Answer (score 1):

$iii)$ With the function $d_2$ you defined as "metric" on the set of integrable functions on $[0,1]$ you have that both the characteristic function of the 0-singleton, $\chi_{\{0\}}$ and the constant function $0$ are integrable, moreover $d_2(\chi_{\{0\}},0)=0$ but they are not equal.
$iv)$Each point in a metric space is closed, finite unions of closed sets are still closed so every set is closed (hence every set is open too)

Comment: It can happen that you have a set which is both closed and open, they are commonly called clopen